# How to add Anchor tag on every database entery using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

/*This is Model*/

```
 <?php
     class home_model extends CI_Model
      {
        public function store()
         {
       $this->db->select('storename');
       $q=$this->db->get('stores');
       return $q;

            }
        }

    ?>
```

/*This is Controller*/

```
 class Home_controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_data = array();
}

public function index()
{

    $this->load->model('home_model');
    $qu=$this->home_model->store();
    $data['query']=$qu;
    $data['main_content'] = 'frontend/home/home';
    $this->load->view('frontend/master_layout', $data);

}
public function selected()
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'frontend/home/selected';
    $this->load->view('frontend/master_layout', $data);
}
```

}

/*This is View and I want to create an anchor tag at every store name by using base_url()*/

```
        <div class="home_right">
    <?php 

         echo "<br>";
         echo "<br>";
         foreach($query->result() as $row)
         {
            echo "<br>".$row->storename."<br>";  
         } 
     ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just `echo` the anchor tag like this

```
<div class="home_right">
    <?php 

         echo "<br>";
         foreach($query->result() as $row)
         {
            echo "<a href=".base_url().$row->storename.">".$row->storename ."</a><br>";  
         } 
     ?>
    </div>
```